# How to give access for a model object to a specific user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am doing an online classroom project in Django where I created a model named *create_course* which is accessible by teachers. Now I am trying to design this as the teacher who creates a class only he can see this after login another teacher shouldn't see  his classes and how to add students into that particular class I created

*the course model*

```
class course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField()
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
```

*views.py*

```
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = add_course(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Class Created Sucessfully")
    context['add_courses'] = form
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', context)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import course

class add_course(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields = ('course_name', 'course_id', 'course_sec', 'classroom_id')
```

Comment: Look into `django permissions` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: This can be done in two ways. 1 - Create one more field like "created_by" in your "course" model. In your views function, check "request.user == course_obj.created_by", this will render the course obj to the user only if it is created by that person. 2 - Create custom permissions, add those permission to the model. Specify that permission in your views. You may need to refer django permissions in detail to implement the second option

Comment: what should i store in "created_by" field the username of the user creating it? and how to do it @B.Anup

Comment: Can you try establishing relationship between course model and user using Foreign key. Then you will be having details about the user who has created the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more field in course model that establish relationship with User model. Hence you can get the details about the teacher who has created course.

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class course(models.Model):
        course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        course_sec = models.IntegerField()
        classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your view function, you can check whether logged in user is same as the created of the requested course.

```
    def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # since this is course specific view, you will be passing an identiier or pk of the course as an argument to this function.
        course_obj = Course.objects.get(id="identifier")
        if request.user == course_obj.created_by:
            # logged in user is same as the creator of the course
        else:
            # redirect
```

I would prefer creating permissions and having those in specific models. You can give it a try with that too. Let me know, if it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks first part is working fine now its saving name of the user who created the object but now I wanna show all of his created class in that teachers home page like rectangular box we can see in  google classroom can you give me some idea about that @B.Anup

Comment: You can use related name that i missed in the above code. Based on user obj of User modal, you can get all the rows of Course that user_obj in relationship with. Below link has the detailed explaination on manytoone relationship, it will help you out.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Can you suggest an idea of how can I show his all-created class in rectangular card view like google classroom? Every time he creates a new class it will appear on his homepage. @B.Anup